# Is a function holomorphic, if it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove, that $f(z)=(z+n)^r$, where $n$ and $r$ are positive integers can be differentiated for any $n$ and $r$.

I have proven, that for any $n$ the function $f(z)=z+n$ will be differentiable by the use of mathematical induction and know, that holomorphic functions, when multiplied keep on being holomorphic, yet am not sure how to show that the function will be holomorphic.

**How could I do that?**

Comment: The cauchy reimann equations only consider how you approach the limit from the real and imaginary axes.

Comment: If a function $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is differentiable in the real sense (as a map $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, then it is holomorphic iff the Cauchy Riemann equations hold. This requirement is pretty crucial, otherwise the function needn't even be continuous!

Comment: Let me also add that differentiability in the real sense follows from continuity of partial derivatives. So you can prove a function holomorphic if you check the partial derivatives are continuous and satisfy the C-R equations.

Comment: When someone told you to  use induction that meant you should use induction on $r$. That makes the problem trivial. (Using induction to show that $z+n$ is holomorphic is just silly...)

Answer (score 1):

You know that $f(z) = z + n$ is holomorphic, and that the product of two holomorphic functions is holomorphic.

Can you prove that $g(z) = (z + n)^2$ is holomorphic? Hint - $(z + n)^2 = (z + n) \times (z + n)$.

What about $h(z) = (z + n)^3$?

Now can you see how to get a proof of the case for $(z + n)^r$?